# Check_cxx() not working with cuda

Tags: waf

I am new to the waf framework of compiling and building a project. Basically I am trying to load the compiler and the library for compiling the `.cu` files. and I have the following line of code taken from `cuda.py` file written by Thomas Nagy

```
self.check_cxx(header='cuda.h', lib='cudart', libpath=_libpath, includes=_includes)
```

`my _libpath` is correctly pointing to `'/usr/local/cuda/lib'` which contains the `libcudart.dylib`. 
but it says it cannot find cudart library.

`libcudart.dylib` is a symbolic link to the `/Developer/Nvidia/cuda5.0/lib/libcudart.dylib`

Can anyone tell what possibly is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working the problem was with the loading of the cxx compiler. The loading of the compiler compiler_cxx was failing because I had written load('cxx') instead of load('compiler_cxx'). After correcting this error the check_cxx was able to load the cuda and cudart libraries. Not sure why it didnt complain about the failure of cxx loading..